# Pure JavaScript way to store a var of a link within a list

Tags: javascript

I can't edit my HTML but I wanted to store a variable of the anchor within a list item so that I can make an `onclick` event.

At the moment nothing seems to work and I'm assuming it's probably the `querySelectorAll` being used incorrectly. Help appreciated.

```js
//set the link class on nav items
var link = document.querySelectorAll('.nodiv a');

console.log(link);

link.onclick = function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 alert("clicked!");
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li class="nodiv"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
 <li class="nodiv"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
 <li class="nodiv"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
 <li class="nodiv"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a **node list**, so you have to loop through the list to get the actual nodes.

```js
//set the link class on nav items
var link = document.querySelectorAll('.nodiv a');

console.log(link);

for (var i = 0; i < link.length; i++) {
    link[i].onclick = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('clicked!');
    }
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li class="nodiv"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
 <li class="nodiv"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
 <li class="nodiv"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
 <li class="nodiv"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ah, that's where I was going wrong. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You tried to add the `onclick` function to an array of elements. You need to set it to one single element like this:

```js
//set the link class on nav items
var link = document.querySelectorAll('.nodiv a');

console.log(link);

for(var i=0;i<link.length;i++) {
    link[i].onclick = function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     alert("clicked!");
    }
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li class="nodiv"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
 <li class="nodiv"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
 <li class="nodiv"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
 <li class="nodiv"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```